# Git ftp: How to upload the "build" folder while it is ignored in .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control, git-ftp

My project uses `git` to source on bitbuckets and `git-ftp` to deploy the build on an FTP.

I want to:

- not track the build in the source file
- not track the source file on the ftp
- track only the `build` folder on the ftp

By now I have:

- In `.gitignore`: `build`
- In `.git-ftp-ignore`: `*`
- In `.git-ftp-include`: `build/*`

But the command `git ftp push` return an message

```
There are no files to sync.
Last deployment changed from  to b0d3d2797796a0bc3c47d0aa128a3abc4cbef9e5.
```

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did

In **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file

```
image: node:10.15.3
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
        - node
        name: Installing
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build   
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --syncroot ./build --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_SERVER
```

And then added a **.git-ftp-include** file which only contains

```
!./build
```